# Не приходят письма с почты

Tags: asp.net-core

Проблема такая. Сделал форму обратной связи. Форма собирает и записывает данные и записывает в БД нормально. Сделал метод, который после записи в БД будет отправлять письма мне на почту.
    Проблема в том, что на моем ноуте т.е на локалке письма приходят сразу все нормально. Но на других компах или смартфонах письмо просто не летит на почту. 
    Дебажил консоль смартфона, консоль на ноуте, проверял бэк, ничего не увидел никаких ошибок. Письма просто не приходят. 
    Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать, идеи закончились совсем!
    Вот пробовал два метода. Оба их них на локалке присылают письма, а если с хостинга или других компов то нет.

```
    public JsonResult SendMessage(GetRequestModel request) {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru");
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("skyexx@mail.ru", "******");
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("skyexx@mail.ru");
            mailMessage.To.Add("skyexx@mail.ru");
            mailMessage.Body = "Имя: " + request.sUserName + "\n" +
                "E-mail или телефон: " + request.sEmailOrNumber + "\n" +
                "Коротко о проекте: " + request.sMultiTextRequest;
            mailMessage.Subject = "Новая заявка";
            client.Send(mailMessage);
            return Json(request);

Также пробовал вот
    var sMessage = new MimeMessage();
            sMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("skyexx@mail.ru"));
            sMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("skyexx@mail.ru"));
            sMessage.Subject = request.sUserName;
            sMessage.Body = new TextPart("html") {
                Text = "Имя: " + request.sUserName + " <br>" +
                "Email или телефон: " + request.sEmailOrNumber + " <br>" +
                "Коротко о проекте: " + request.sMultiTextRequest
            };
            using (var client = new SmtpClient()) {
                //client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Connect("smtp.mail.ru");
                client.Authenticate("skyexx@mail.ru", "******");
                client.Send(sMessage);
                client.Disconnect(false);
            }
            return View("Index");
```

Answer (score 0):

Как всегда спасибо всем за помощь. Если кому пригодится. Проблему решил изменив порт с 25 на 587, также вместо шифрования SSL использовал TLS и все заработало.

```
public async Task SendEmailAsync(GetRequestModel request) {
        try {
            var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();
            emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("********"));
            emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("********"));
            emailMessage.Subject = "Новая заявка";
            emailMessage.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Html) {
                Text = "Имя: " + request.sUserName + "\n" +
            "E-mail или телефон: " + request.sEmailOrNumber + "\n" +
            "Коротко о проекте: " + request.sMultiTextRequest
        };
            using (var client = new SmtpClient()) {
                await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.mail.ru", 587, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
                await client.AuthenticateAsync("********", "*********");
                await client.SendAsync(emailMessage);
                await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```